# how to get value from alert in Java script in MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form with textbox which uses autocomplete functionality. I need to get the value from javascript to my text box. I have my desired value in an alert message but I can't store that value to my textbox. My code is below.

```
$(function () {
    $("#Name").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("GetProducts")',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.value);
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class=" form-group " style="width:30%">
    <label>Search By Name</label> @Html.TextBox("Name", null, new { id = "Name" })
</div>
```

Comment: Edit your question and paste your code there instead of pasting in comments. And yes do take care of the formatting of the code!

Comment: I have edited this to correct the formatting twice but you keep overwriting it.

Comment: sorry now i post the exact question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `ui.item.value` to `value` attribute of textbox. Like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Name").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetProducts")',
            select: function (event, ui) {
               $('#Name').attr('value',ui.item.value);
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```